# Как присвоить результат подзапроса переменной для дальнейшего использования в запросе SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть запрос, в котором необходимо сравнить поле с вычисляемой переменной.

Переменная:

```
COUNT(SELECT DISTINCT format FROM TABLE1)
```

В этом же запросе я хочу добавить в условие WHERE сравнение поля с этой переменной

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE2
WHERE T2.Field<вычисленная переменная
```

Как это сделать в рамках одного запроса ?

Comment: какой то странный у вас count, обычно все таки пишется `select count(distinct format from TABLE1)`. А переменные ни к чему, SQL это конструктор, один запрос можно включать практически в любое место другого, так что прямо сам запрос в скобках ставите и все

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо вам нужно что то вроде

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE2
  WHERE T2.Field < (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT format) FROM TABLE1)
```

Но могут быть разные варианты написания и использования в зависимости от других потребностей в запросе и с целями оптимизации